# How do I make a drop down menu behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
<script>  
function init()
{      
    
    document.getElementById("header").onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById('subtwo').style.display = 'none';   
    } 


window.onload=init;
</script>
```

```css
<style>
    * { 
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        font: 1.2em Verdana, sans-serif;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
    }

    h2, h3 {
       text-align: center;  
    }
    p {
        padding: 0.5em 0.2em;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: crimson;
        display: block;
    }
    
    #header {
        background-color: tan;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
    #mainMenu {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #mainMenu li {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;

        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }

    #leftBar, #rightBar {
        padding-top: 2em;
    }
    #leftBar {
        float: left;
        width: 8em;
    }

    #leftBar li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    #leftBar li:first-child {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
    }
    #leftBar a, #mainMenu a {
        padding: .25em 0;
    }
    #rightBar {
        float: right;
        width: 8em;
        padding-left: 0.4em;
    }

    #main {
        padding: 2em 5px 1em 5px;
        border: 1px solid tan;
        border-width: 0 8em;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    #footer ul {
        padding: 10px 8em;
    }
 #footer li {
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        text-align: center;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    #footer li:last-child {
        border-right-style: none;
    }

    #leftBar a:hover, #mainMenu a:hover {
        color: black;
        background-color: #ccc;
        background-color: peru;
    }
    #footer a:hover {
        display:inline;
        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }
    .submenu {
        background-color: gold;
        border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: .5em;
    }
    #subone {
        height:100px;
    }
    #subtwo {
        height: 120px;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h2>Lab8 - Submenus</h2>
</div>
    
<div id="mainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li id="one"><a href="#"> Home &nbsp; </a></li>
        <li id="two"><a href="#"> About Us &nbsp;&#9660;</a></li>
        <li id="three"><a href="#"> Directory &nbsp;&#9660;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Map </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    
<div id ="subone" class ="submenu">
    <h3>The first submenu. </h3>
</div>
                       
<div id ="subtwo" class ="submenu">
    <h3>The second submenu.</h3>
</div>
    
<div id="leftBar">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Link 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Link 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Link 3 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Link 4 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Link 5 </a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
    
<div id="rightBar">
    <p>
        Here is perhaps a small related article.
    </p>
    <p>And perhaps a few more links</p>
</div>
    
<div id="main">
    <h3> Content Heading </h3>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Vivamus vehicula, lorem sed hendrerit auctor, sapien dolor
    consectetur enim, nec pharetra odio orci nec massa.
    Duis suscipit elit libero, sit amet cursus ante. 
    Mauris laoreet tellus in urna suscipit ornare. 
    Aenean erat purus, commodo in aliquet et, aliquet at quam.
    </p><p>
    Suspendisse commodo imperdiet dolor mattis scelerisque. 
    Morbi blandit sem ac augue gravida sed vehicula augue blandit. 
    Mauris hendrerit vestibulum faucibus. 
    Integer tellus augue, adipiscing id commodo vitae, volutpat id nunc. 
    Maecenas ultrices, ante a commodo rutrum, sapien purus consectetur nibh, 
    id auctor erat lectus ac purus. Morbi id suscipit nunc. 
    </p>
</div>
    
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://csci.viu.ca/~hohman/"> Bill H </a></li>
        <li><a href="https://validator.w3.org/"> HTML  </a></li>
        <li><a href="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/"> CSS </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

I firstly want to add a few CSS rules to position and then “hide” the submenus and then add JavaScript event handlers to create the drop-down menu behaviour. If someone can tell how to do that, I would really appreciate it.
If I click on a word, a drop down will pop, If I click on the page anywhere it will go.

[A copy of a similar webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbbw3.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** / details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is baked into HTML. Unless you really need to recreate the wheel, just use what's already implemented for you like below. [source MDN Select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

> ```
> <!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
> <select name="text"> <!--Supplement an id here instead of using 'text'-->
>   <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
>   <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
>   <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
> </select>
> ```

If you're looking for most aesthetically pleasing UI, try a library like Twitter's Bootstrap or Google's Material Components Web.